# How to add event handler to span with diacritical symbol (arabic)?

Tags: html, css, hover, arabic, diacritics

I want to split arabic words letter by letter, paint them to different colors and add event handler on them.

[Image, how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl0Ky.png)

I realized part of idea about painting, and handle on the consonant letters (harf), but I haven't find way to add event handler to diacritical symbols, witch indicates wovels (harakat) in arabic language.

Handle ":hover" fires on "#harf" elements, but doesn't fire on "#harakat" elements.

Then I want to use "onclick" and other events too. But I suppose , they will not work on the span with a diacritical symbol inside of it.

Is there a solution?

```
<div class="arabic-text">
<span id=harf-1>ف&zwj;</span><span id=harakat-1>َ</span><span id=harf-2>&zwj;ع&zwj;</span><span id=harakat-2>َ</span><span id=harf-3>&zwj;ل</span><span id=harakat-3>َ</span>
<span id=harf-1>ف&zwj;</span><span id=harakat-1>َ</span><span id=harf-2>&zwj;ع&zwj;</span><span id=harakat-2>ِ</span><span id=harf-3>&zwj;ل</span><span id=harakat-3>َ</span>
<span id=harf-1>ف&zwj;</span><span id=harakat-1>َ</span><span id=harf-2>&zwj;ع&zwj;</span><span id=harakat-2>ُ</span><span id=harf-3>&zwj;ل</span><span id=harakat-3>َ</span>

</div>

<style>

#harf-1 {color:darkred }
#harf-2 {color:darkblue }
#harf-3 {color: darkgreen}

#harf-1:hover {color:red }
#harf-2:hover {color:red }
#harf-3:hover {color:red }

#harakat-3 {color:darkred }
#harakat-2 {color:darkblue }
#harakat-1 {color: darkgreen}

#harakat-3:hover {color:red }
#harakat-2:hover {color:red }
#harakat-1:hover {color: red}

.arabic-text {
font-family: Lateef; 
font-size: 300%;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the content per-se, but the fact that the spans containing the diacritical have a width  of zero px, hence there is no area to `hover`

You can play with your test case by adding a generic css that add borders ([see at the link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNGoBp)) then try adding the padding so that all characters have some "area", hover should work

```
span{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #333;
  /*padding-left:10px;*/
}
```

Comment: Good ideas, about with. But it doesn't work. When I set width of span with diacritics (harakat) , we have gap between letters (harf) , but not space around diacritics .

Comment: use `position: relative` then reposition with something like `left: -1em` and with proper `z-index`,  you can make use of `display: inline-block` and set height so that is does not cover the other letters. Anway, the `width` part solves the hover problem as a start